# Sum of elements on the way to largest leaf in BST

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to sum all the nodes on the way to the largest leaf in a binary search tree. The nodes contain only positive numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef int ElType;

typedef struct Tree {
    ElType key;
    struct Tree *left;
    struct Tree *right;
} Tree;

Tree* InsertBST(Tree* t, int k)
{
    if (t == NULL) {
        Tree* w = (Tree*) malloc(sizeof(Tree));
        w->key = k;
        w->left = NULL;
        w->right = NULL;
        return w;
    }

    if (k <= t->key)
        t->left = InsertBST(t->left, k);
    else
        t->right = InsertBST(t->right, k);

    return t;
}

int SumMaxOfBST(Tree* t, int *sum_max)
{
    if (t == NULL) {
        *sum_max = -1;
        return *sum_max;
    }

    if (t->right == NULL) {
        *sum_max += t->key;
        return *sum_max;
    }

    *sum_max += t->key;

    *sum_max += SumMaxOfBST(t->right, sum_max);
    return *sum_max;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    srand (time(NULL));

    Tree* t = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        t = InsertBST(t, rand() % 1000);

    int sum_way = 0;
    int a = SumMaxOfBST(t, sum_way);

      printf("Sum on the way to the largest leaf %d:\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

This exits with non-zero status. My strong suspicion is that I have botched the use of pointers, however, after several rewrites and videos on the use of pointers I still don't seem to grasp what's going on. If I understand correctly,`*sum_max += x` should increment the value of `sum_max` by `x`. At which point is my use of pointers off?

Comment: Your compiler should be complaining about the absence of an `&` before `sum_way` in the call `int a = SumMaxOfBST(t, sum_way);`.  Heed your compilers warnings — the compiler is right and you're wrong, at least at this stage of your C coding career.

Comment: Also, `<stdlib.h>` declares `malloc()` et al.  There's no need to include `<malloc.h>` unless you're using the extended features of the header.  Also, your code provides no way for you to verify whether the answer you get is right; you don't print the tree, so you've no way of knowing whether your calculation is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get why you take a pointer to int as a paramter for `SumMaxOfBST`, I think the function written like this is simpler.

```
int SumMaxOfBST(Tree* t)
{
    if (t == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (t->right == NULL) {
        return t->key;
    }
    return t->+key + SumMaxOfBST(t->right);
}
```

Furthermore in your `main`, you're passing `sum_way` that is an `int`, while `SumMaxOfBST` expects an `int*`. You should pass `&sum_way` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed is a lot cleaner than my attempt.